# New Angular App: ng new or dotnet new angular?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, dotnet-cli

I'm about to start a new Angular application. It will serve as the frontend to an ASP.NET Core Web API.  Because all of the code I have so far is managed within a single dotnet solution, I thought it would be convenient to be able to add the frontend project to it.

While looking into how to achieve this, I learned that the dotnet cli has a template for angular applications.

I created one to see what it looked like, and as far as I can tell, it's an angular app served by a lean ASP.NET Core Web Server.

I was hoping to gain a better understanding of what pros/cons there are when creating an angular app using the angular cli, vs using the dotnet cli? Beyond the convenience of keeping the project in the same solution, I'm not sure which way to go with, or why I would choose one over the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dotnet vs angular cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729639/dotnet-vs-angular-cli)

Comment: These questions are dated, but shed some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729639/dotnet-vs-angular-cli/43738028

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502744/what-are-the-differences-between-a-dotnet-cli-and-a-angular-cli-basic-project-te

Based on these answers, it seems like it's wiser to stick with the Angular CLI.